# Node.js - How to get custom environment variable with config?

Tags: node.js

I am running `config@1.29.4` and I am attempting to get settings from the environment variables using  `.\config\custom-environment-variables.json` does not work. However, it reads from the `.\config\default.json` just fine.

`.\config\custom-environment-variables.json`

```
{
  "jwtPrivateKey": "sс_jwtPrivateKey"
}
```

`.\config\default.json`

```
{
  "jwtPrivateKey": "default"
}
```

`console.log(config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))`
always prints
`default`

I made this in cmd: `SET sс_jwtPrivateKey=12345678`

I tried new version of config, the same situation.

It prints nothing when I set the key property in config/default to an empty string. How can I resolve this?

How to get the value of `sc_jwtPrivateKey`?

THANK YOU!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618898/nodejs-config-cannot-not-load-custom-environment-variables
It didn't help.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as follows:
Instead `SET sс_jwtPrivateKey=12345678`, I used `SETX sс_jwtPrivateKey 12345678`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following command in windows powershell to set the value of `sc_jwtPrivateKey`

```
$env:sс_jwtPrivateKey="12345678"
```

Or try this following in cmd

```
set sс_jwtPrivateKey=12345678
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an **External Terminal** not the **Integrated Terminal**